# sizeof operator explanation

Tags: c

Here is a C code snippet

```
char *p="Hello World";
int a;
char b;
printf("%d\n",sizeof(p++));
printf("%c\n",*p);

printf("%d",sizeof(a,b));
printf("%d",sizeof(b,a));
```

Here is the output

```
4
H
1
4
```

Can anybody explain why p didn't get incremented and what is the use of comma operator here. I read that it has something to do with VLAs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`p` didn't get incremented because `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand, it just uses the type of the expression.

`sizeof` is an operator taking a single expression as its operand, *not* a parenthesized argument list. So, in `sizeof(a,b)`, the single operand is `(a,b)`. The comma in `sizeof(a,b)` therefore is the comma operator -- unlike the comma in `printf("%c\n", *p)`, which is an argument separator and not the comma operator.

When evaluated, the comma operator first evaluates its left-hand side, then evaluates the right-hand side. The result of the operator is the result of the right-hand side. So, although `(a,b)` isn't evaluated, the type of the expression is the type of the right-hand side. Hence `sizeof(a,b)` is equivalent to `sizeof(b)`. Really there's no "use" of the comma operator here, at least no useful use. It's pointless other than to test your ability to read it.

It has nothing to do with VLAs (variable-length arrays).

What does have to do with VLAs is that when `sizeof` is applied to a VLA, it *is* defined to evaluate the expression (6.5.3.4/2 in C99). The size of a VLA is of course not known at compile-time.

But, when used on the RHS of a comma operator, the name of a VLA decays to a pointer just like any other array does. This is 6.3.2.1/3: there are three cases where an array does not decay, and "the operand of sizeof" is one of them but "the RHS of a comma operator" is not. So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int b[a]; // VLA
    const char *p = "Hello";
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(++p, b));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof b);
    printf("%c", *p);
}
```

prints (on my machine):

```
4
40
H
```

because in the first `sizeof`, even though there's a VLA on the RHS of the comma operator, the type of the operand of `sizeof` is `int*`, not a VLA, and so `(++p, b)` is not evaluated. In the second `sizeof`, the type of the operand is a VLA, which *is* evaluated, and its size is `10*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: It is not true that sizeof doesn't evaluate its operand, it does evaluate it during pre-processing, but the operand is simply not included in the resulting binary, it was replaced by a number. If you type `printf("%d\n",sizeof(a + b));` you can see that you get the result 4, because the operand was evaluated according to the integer promotion and balancing rules.

Comment: @Lundin: that's not *evaluating* the operand, that's just parsing it. We know that the type resulting from adding an `int` and a `char` is `int`, without performing the addition itself. See 6.5.3.4/2 (which also points out that I need to edit my answer...)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` operator is a compiler function (e.g. calculated to constant at compile time).

1. This means: p++ is ignored, only the type of p is used.
2. When there is a comma, the last parameter is used (so, for example `sizeof(a,b)` is like `sizeof(b)`)

Comment: `sizeof` is not always calculated at compile time, for example, with variable-length arrays.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you. (though it is not related to this question)

Comment: It is not true that sizeof doesn't evaluate its operand, it does evaluate it during pre-processing, but the operand is simply not included in the resulting binary, it was replaced by a number. If you type `printf("%d\n",sizeof(a + b));` you can see that you get the result 4, because the operand was evaluated according to the integer promotion and balancing rules.

Comment: @Lundin: you are failing to distinguish between evaluating the `sizeof`, and evaluating the *operand* of the sizeof. It is false to say that `sizeof` evaluates its operand, at compile-time or any other time, unless the operand has a VLA type. The standard clearly states that it doesn't.

Comment: @Steve My point is that sizeof doesn't magically get a type handed to it depending on what the type of the variable handed to it happened to be. It has to understand the expression, and what operator that is being used in it, to know which implicit type promotions to use. And regarding who evaluates what... what about the case where the operand of sizeof contains only constants? Take this for example: sizeof(1<2? a : b). The operand must and will be evaluated for sizeof to know what type that's referred to.

Comment: @Lundin: no, the operand is not evaluated. The type of `1<2?a : b` is the common type of `a` and `b`, according to the slightly fiddly rules of the `?:` conditional operator. Which part of 6.5.3.4/2 in the standard, "If the type of the operand is a variable length array
type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated" do you disagree with? `sizeof` needs to work out the type of the operand expression, but in C, it is not necessary to evaluate an expression in order to know its type. Observe that `sizeof(1<2?a:b) == sizeof(2<1?a:b)`.